# VB initialise an array over more than one line

Tags: arrays, vb.net, initialization

I'm  C programmer that has to do a bit of VB. I need to initialise an array and it won't compile.
What is wrong with this,

```
   Dim array() As Integer = {
        &H0, &H80, &H2, &H2, &H33, &H0, &H0, &H1A, &H53, &H79, &H51, &H75, &H65, &H73, &H74, &H20
        ,&H53, &H79, &H4A, &H65, &H74, &H2D, &H53, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20
        ,&H30, &H31, &H31, &H31}
```

It has all the right characters in the correct order.
I assume its the commas at the start of the line.
Is there something in the VB standard that makes this illegal?

Comment: add an underscore _ before the linebreaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB, you need to either use the line continuation character `_` at the end of the line, or put the line break after the comma instead of before.

```
Dim array() As Integer = {
    &H0, &H80, &H2, &H2, &H33, &H0, &H0, &H1A, &H53, &H79, &H51, &H75, &H65, &H73, &H74, &H20,
    &H53, &H79, &H4A, &H65, &H74, &H2D, &H53, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20 _
    , &H30, &H31, &H31, &H31}
```

Comment: Ahh so underscore is loosly similar to \ in C for multiline #define. Putting the comma at the end of the line solved the problem

Comment: @SimonRees the explicit version (underscore) goes way, way back.  The auto ability after a comma works for many, many things like long linq statements, stacks of `If()` operators, method declarations etc etc etc

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment earlier:

```
Dim array() As Integer = {
    &H0, &H80, &H2, &H2, &H33, &H0, &H0, &H1A, &H53, &H79, &H51, &H75, &H65, &H73, &H74, &H20 _
    , &H53, &H79, &H4A, &H65, &H74, &H2D, &H53, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20, &H20 _
    , &H30, &H31, &H31, &H31}
```